# R - subset and include calculated column

Tags: r, calculated-columns, dplyr

Let's say I have this simple data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,3,1,3,1), y = c(2,2,2,2,2,2),z = c('a','b','c','d','e','f'))

> df
  x y z
1 1 2 a
2 3 2 b
3 3 2 c
4 1 2 d
5 3 2 e
6 1 2 f
```

I would like to subset where `x= 3`, return only column `x` and `y` and include a calculated colum `x+y`.
I can get the first 2 things done, but I can't get the caclulated column to also appear.

```
df[df$x==3,c("x","y")]
```

How can I do that, but using `base R` only.

Comment: Try `transform(df[df$x==3,c("x","y")], new = x + y)` or with `mutate` `library(dplyr);df %>% select(x, y) %>% filter(x==3) %>% mutate(new = x + y)`

Answer (score 1):

Staying in `base`, just do a `rowSums` before your subset.

```
df$xy <- rowSums(df[, c("x", "y")])
df[df$x == 3, c("x", "y", "xy")]

#   x y xy
# 2 3 2  5
# 3 3 2  5
# 5 3 2  5
```

Personally, I do prefer the `dplyr` approach, which @akrun commented on your question.

Comment: I can't use `dplyr` because of security on the computer. 
`rowSum()` looks good, much better than what I have been doing so far.
I like `transform()` since it allows me to do it in the same chunck of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,3,3,1,3,1), y = c(2,2,2,2,2,2),z = c('a','b','c','d','e','f'))

df$z <- ifelse(df$x == 3, (df$x + df$y), df$y)
df

  x y z
1 1 2 2
2 3 2 5
3 3 2 5
4 1 2 2
5 3 2 5
6 1 2 2
```